# What's the highest possible value for the laravel lifetime config variable in session.php

Tags: laravel, session, session-variables

By default laravel sessions expire after two hours, I know this is for security but I have a web app which has a mobile app(android webview). Users keep complaining that they need to login each time they come to the app. As a temporal solution I will like to know how I can set this variable to "forever". thanks in advance

```
 'lifetime' => 120
```

what I want

```
'lifetime' => infinity
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Max integer value in PHP is `2147483647` for 32 bit platform and Laravel multiplies `lifetime` value by 60.

So maximum `lifetime` value is `35791394` for 32-bit platform. It's 68 years, so it's kind of infinity for the session. )

Comment: whats the maximum value for 64bits... my bad I should find out but no time pls

Comment: I guess it's `153722867280912930` for 64 bit platform.

Comment: When i use this as you said I get "The cookie expiration time is not valid.
". @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: How to make lifetime for different guards separately?