# Laravel 5 - stay logged in forever

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to put in the `login` page a checkbox "stay logged in".

That should never end the session of the user unless the user logs out.

I know that in app/config/session.php I have these variables:

```
'lifetime' => 60,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

But I wanted to maintain alive the session forever, and not be removed if the user close his navigator.

Any ideas on how should I proceed?
Thanks

Comment: I don't believe you can set it to never expire, but there is no upper limit, so you can set it to something like 100 years.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Laravel has a built-in feature to [remember users](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#remembering-users), I'd strongly recommend using it.

> If you would like to provide "remember me" functionality in your
>   application, you may pass a boolean value as the second argument to
>   the attempt method, which will keep the user authenticated
>   indefinitely, or until they manually logout. Of course, your users
>   table must include the string remember_token column, which will be
>   used to store the "remember me" token.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
    // The user is being remembered...
}
```

if you want to solve the problem manually, there is workaround for this: you have to set the expires date of your cookie to a date in the wide future, somewhat like 2050. this is technically not forever, but should usually be long enough.

Comment: I just follow the "remember users" link that you wrote, but there is no need of a workaround like you said. Just setting the second parameter of ´attempt´ function is working:  ´Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], Input::get('remember_me', false))´ .

Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked for you. :) I meant that the workaround is the other option if you don't wanna use the remember-me feature. updated my answer to make this clear.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but still session getting expire after some time like 24mins of inactivity. code is correctly placed but still the problem is same.

Answer (score 7):

You can set `lifetime` option to `35791394`. It's a [maximum possible number for 32-bit machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333527/whats-the-highest-possible-value-for-the-laravel-lifetime-config-variable-in-se):

```
'lifetime' => 35791394, // Session will expire in 68 years.
```

Comment: Yes, but what happend with the users that doesn't want to be remembered?

Comment: After setting session time, what happens to normal logout who logged in without remember me token ??

Comment: This will also affect the sessions of people who aren't logged in, including any bots, like an Elastic Beanstalk healthcheck. I wouldn't recommend it. (After an hour or two I had 1,700 "ELB-Healthcheck" sessions in my database -- that won't expire for 68 years with this change.)

Comment: If you do this and using redis as session driver, will soon encounter redis savedb problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can set some big values. I have tried now at 7900 years

> i.e, 365*24*60*7990 = 4152240000 minutes

```
  'lifetime' => 4152240000
```

Comment: Will not work for 32-bit systems and for 64-bit system max number is [`153722867280912930`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333527/whats-the-highest-possible-value-for-the-laravel-lifetime-config-variable-in-se)

Comment: I have tried on my system. my system is 64 bit. This is what maximum i can tried. laravel giving error taht not more than 9999 years but not taking 9999 years.

Comment: Laravel 5.3, Mac OS (64-bit) value from my previous comment works just fine.

Comment: Strange but i don't know why? your given value is working fine, but I have tried with 4204800000 value which is 8000 years (8000*365*24*60) and its not working. can you please check in your laptop. My os is Ubantu 14.04. So last night after checking on this value I have given the above answer

Comment: Yes, I get the same exception for your integer. Exception is generated by Symfony component. I'd still recommend to use `35791394` which will work for all configurations.

Comment: This will also affect the sessions of people who aren't logged in, including any bots. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: 9999 years... wow. If your site is active for that amount of time, whatever storage your session driver is using would have ran out... why care so much about the future?