# active session login - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to not log out of users who enter the application?

for exple, **if a user closes the application, I need it to be open and not require a new login again.**

Comment: From [stay logged in forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010680/laravel-5-stay-logged-in-forever) you can get idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 - stay logged in forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010680/laravel-5-stay-logged-in-forever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **config/session.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120), // either change in your .env file, if there, or the default number to 9999 (minutes)

'expire_on_close' => false, // this is what you are looking for
```