# make website always connected to session never logout

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am working on a project which is based on sitting an online test. The test can last upwards of 3 hours, this causes the session to be destroyed due to a timeout. Which means the test ends up not being submitted as there is no longer an active session. Is there a way using ajax for example, that I can keep the session active?

The project is in Laravel 5.3

Comment: Do an ajax request to an dummy php file starting the session every ten minutes causing the server to extend the session period

Comment: I suggested an edit to make it easier to read. :) Please review!

Answer (score 4):

In `config/session.php` set `lifetime`:

```
'lifetime' => 35791394,
```

`35791394` is maximum lifetime for 32-bit machines because [Laravel will multiply this number by 60](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41333576/1227923).

Comment: I also have to change php .ini file to increase the session time please suggest